# strange droppable() bug on iPad, works on iPhone

Tags: ios, html, ipad, cordova, droppable

I've tried various web searches, but I can't seem to find anything that relates to my problem.

To quickly delineate the problem:

1. HTML5 Cordova iOS app (7.1 -> 8.1)
2. uses draggable elements
3. I only have issues on the iPad, not on the iPhone
4. The HTML5 app itself works flawlessly in a web-browser

The app itself is a biology app that teaches translation - decoding RNA into a amino acid sequence, i.e. a protein.

For this, the user sees the sequence and drags the correct amino acid onto it. The amino acid is a draggable element and the target div is a droppable. One amino acid at a time a chain is built. Please refer to the screenshot to get an idea (can't embed yet).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4UpF.png

In order to fit all screens, I "transform: scale" the app accordingly (fixed size is ~850x550). And to get rid of the associated jQuery bug with draggable (object movement would also change with the scaling factor), I've followed the instructions at http://gungfoo.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/jquery-ui-resizabledraggable-with-transform-scale-set/

```
// scaling to fit viewport
    // sizing the page
    var myPage = $('.page');
    var pageWidth=myPage.width();
    var pageHeight=myPage.height();

    // sizing the iFrame
    var myFrame = $('.container');
    var frameWidth=myFrame.width();
    var frameHeight=myFrame.height();

    // scaleFactor horizontal
    var horizontalScale=pageWidth/frameWidth;

    // scaleFactor vertiacal
    var verticalScale=pageHeight/frameHeight;

    // global zoomScale variable
    var zoomScale = 1; // default, required for draggable debug

    // if page fits vertically - scale horizontally
    if ((frameHeight * horizontalScale) <= pageHeight) {
        myFrame.css({
            'transform': 'scale('+horizontalScale+')',
            'transform-origin': 'top',
        });

        // adding vertical margin, if possible
        if (pageHeight > frameHeight*horizontalScale) {
            var heightDifference = pageHeight - frameHeight*horizontalScale;
            myPage.css({
                'margin-top': heightDifference/2,
                'height': pageHeight - heightDifference/2, 
            });
        }
        zoomScale = horizontalScale;
    // else scale vertically
    } else {
        myFrame.css({
            'transform': 'scale('+verticalScale+')',
            'transform-origin': 'top',
        });
        zoomScale = verticalScale;
    }

    // draggable + scale transform fixes (http://gungfoo.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/jquery-ui-resizabledraggable-with-transform-scale-set/)
function startFix(event, ui) {
    ui.position.left = 0;
    ui.position.top = 0;
}

function dragFix(event, ui) {
    var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left; // find change in left
    var newLeft = ui.originalPosition.left + changeLeft / zoomScale; // adjust new left by our zoomScale

    var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top; // find change in top
    var newTop = ui.originalPosition.top + changeTop / zoomScale; // adjust new top by our zoomScale

    ui.position.left = newLeft;
    ui.position.top = newTop;
}
```

I've already got a beta version on iTunes connect and it works great on an iPhone. **On iPads, however, the droppable area is oddly small and shifted**. That is, the div seems to be properly rendered - it is the box with the dashed border.

Has anyone else encountered a similar bug? I really have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem.

The issue was probably based on the viewport meta tag (0.5 scaling) interacting badly with the transform:scale resizing.

Simply removing all viewport meta arguments have solved the problem.